# Sequential sorting in multi-indexed Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, set

I have a multi-indexed Pandas dataframe of numerical values. I wish to sequentially sort each row in a subset of the data frame using two other subsets of the data. I believe the example below would better illustrate what I need:

Consider this example data set:

```
                         A          B          C          D
rtr  2015-01-31  -1.085631  -0.204201   1.730024   1.710438
     2015-02-28   0.997345   1.979348   1.232650  -0.056341
key1 2015-01-31   6.180000   0.990000   2.440000   1.920000
     2015-02-28   1.140000   1.810000   4.560000   0.740000
key2 2015-01-31  86.000000  36.000000  61.000000  34.000000
     2015-02-28  97.000000  96.000000  48.000000  98.000000
```

Consider the last rows of `key1`, `key2`, and `rtr` under date `2015-02-28`:

1. in `df.loc['key1']`, get the column names of the 2 largest values. (ie: C,B)
2. exclude the C and B columns from the column space. (ie: cols remaining: A,D)
3. in `df.loc['key2']`, get the column name of the largest value in the remaining column space. (ie: Of values in columns A and D, D is larger -> return D)
4. fetch corresponding values from `df.loc['rtr']` that correspond to the column names found in steps 1 and 3 (ie: returns values `df.loc['rtr'].loc['20150228',['C','B','D']]`

> ```
> In [140]: df.loc['rtr'].loc['20150228',['C','B','D']]
> Out[140]:
> C    1.232650
> B    1.979348
> D   -0.056341
> Name: 2015-02-28 00:00:00, dtype: float64
> ```

Code for example data generation:

```
## generate data:
d1,d2,d3 = {},{},{}
np.random.seed(123)
for col in list("ABCD"):
    d1[col] = np.random.randn(2)
    d2[col] = np.random.gamma(2,3,2).round(2)
    d3[col] = np.random.random_integers(0,100, 2)
t_index = pd.date_range(start = '2015-01-31', periods = 2, freq = "M")

dat1 = pd.DataFrame(d1, index = t_index)
dat2 = pd.DataFrame(d2, index = t_index)
dat3 = pd.DataFrame(d3, index = t_index)

df = pd.concat([dat1, dat2, dat3], keys = ['rtr', 'key1', 'key2'])
```

Comment: It still isn't clear what you want.

Comment: Hi mate, could you clarify on which part(s) is unclear?

Comment: You applied asterisk on sample data that only for `2015-01-31`.  It would be helpful to provide a better understanding of what the expected output will look like.  When I see questions that need answering, I make a judgement call on how long I think it will take me to answer the question.  I then balance this with my current work load.  Finally, if my eyes glaze over as I read the question, I skip it.  It's in your best interest to make it as easy for someone to read and understand as possible.

Comment: I hope I fixed the issues you mentioned and reformatted the question to make it shorter. Thanks for pointing out the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**: solve the problem for a given date.

```
df1 = df.xs('2015-01-31', level=1)

columns = df1.loc['key1'].nlargest(2).index.tolist()
columns.append(df1.loc['key2'][df.columns.difference(columns)].idxmax())
df1.loc['rtr', columns]
```

We use `nlargest` and take the index of the result because `idxmax` only works for one maximum. We use `idxmax` in the following line, after excluding the previous columns with pandas' index [difference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) method.

**Step 2**: use `groupby` to apply the above solution to each date individually.

```
def func(df2):
    df1 = df2.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
    columns = df1.loc['key1'].nlargest(2).index.tolist()
    columns.append(df1.loc['key2'][df.columns.difference(columns)].idxmax())
    return df1.loc['rtr', columns]

df.groupby(level=1).apply(func)
```

The `reset_index` is added because, in contrast with `xs`, `groupby` does not drop the index level.

Comment: Excellent solution! I'll likely resolve to using `nlargest(m).index.tolist()` in the second step too as this is intended to generalize to a much larger dataset and multiple selections for each key.  I would've never thought to use `groupby` as I've instead have been battling with `np.argsort` and `df.apply`. Thanks for the code!